Need help for understanding tainted funds
I recently sent Sats to my wallet at a major exchange, and they blocked my account saying the money is tainted. I don’t understand this at all since I accumulated the money through different legal dev projects over time.
Is there any tool or way I could verify the taint on my own?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Does this answer your question? Procedure for calculating taint?
